# How create an HTML tag only with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML tag like below :

```html
<div id="Code_G" class="editor-group">
    editor-group<br />
    <div id="Code_L" class="editor-label ">
          editor-label
    </div>
    <div id="Code_F" class="editor-field ">
          editor-field
    </div>
</div>
```

I must give style with CSS to this tags without any changing in the HTML tags to make an input like below picture. The id="Code_F" must be converted to an input tag. How can I do this only with CSS ?

[image]

The most important thing is that this job must be done without any adding element to the HTML tags or any direct changing in the HTML tags and all the changes must be done with CSS!
Any help will be appriciated!

Comment: Note: the `<br>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: This is impossible with CSS; CSS is *presentation* it can only change the presentation - and in some ways the interaction - of HTML, it cannot create or insert new elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#Code_G {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #d9d3d3;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;      
}
#Code_L {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 16px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #000;
}
#Code_F {
  min-height: 46px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 4px; 
  padding: 15px 15px 10px 15px;
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #495057;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Code_G" class="editor-group">
    editor-group<br />
    <div id="Code_L" class="editor-label ">
          editor-label
    </div>
    <div id="Code_F" class="editor-field ">
          editor-field
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can use the [css content property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp) to generate / replace content like this.

```
p:after {
    content: "lorem";
}
```

If you want to alter the html, you would have to use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way you could programmatically create/delete/replace DOM elements using using HTML/CSS. Such requires Javascript, or creating the elements manually, even the `pseudo element`like `after` can only do so much since there is no way you could add a working input inside the content property, here is a way you could use in javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to create a basic input field</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">create</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  x.setAttribute("type", "text");
  x.setAttribute("value", "this is a simple input");
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `fieldset` and `legend` for this purpose.

```css
legend {
  text-align:right
}
.output {
    font: 1rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}
input {
  border:none;
  width:100%;
  outline:none;
}
fieldset {
 border-radius:5px;
  width:400px;
}
input::placeholder {
 text-align:right
}
```

```html
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>editor-field</legend>
        <input type="text" id="monster" name="monster" placeholder="editor-field">
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I must not make any changes in the HTML.